# customized android dumpsys meminfo

Tags: android, logging, memory-management, sampling

How can I write my own code to use the "meminfo" system service? Or how can I add my own system service? My goal is to sample memory usage data automatically as the app runs, and analyze the data postmortem.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I write my own code to use the "meminfo" system service?

There is no "meminfo" system service, per se. To access the code that generates all the "meminfo" output, you would need to write a customized version of the Android OS that contains your code (and modifications to Android as needed).

That being said, some of the "meminfo" data is from `ActivityManager` and `getProcessMemoryInfo()`. [Dianne Hackborn has an epic SO answer on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2299813/115145).

> Or how can I add my own system service?

See above.

> My goal is to sample memory usage data automatically as the app runs, and analyze the data postmortem.

Assuming `getProcessMemoryInfo()` has what you need, you should be able to do this from an ordinary SDK application.

Comment: I did read that post before. Problem is the information exposed by `ActivityManager.MemoryInfo` is fewer than what is described in the post. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.MemoryInfo.html